# Upload part of a page or one picture from the page - the first (as soon as possible)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jsp

I am using AngularJS 1.4, and this is the code for my page

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
   <div ng-controller="mainController">
     <div ng-controller="first">       //  this is ng-include - first.html
        <img id="bannerImage"/> 
     </div>
     <div ng-controller="first2">       //  this is ng-include - first2.html
        <img id="bannerImage1"/> 
     </div>     
     <div ng-controller="first3">       //  this is ng-include - first3.html
        <img id="bannerImage2"/> 
     </div>                                   
     <div ng-controller="second">      //  this is ng-include - second.html
         <img id="mainImage"/>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I need to first load "mainImage.jpg" in "second.html", but judging by the console loads all in the following sequence:

```
first.html
first2.html
first3.html
second.html
bannerImage.jpg
mainImage.jpg 
mainImage2.jpg
mainImage3.jpg             as include order in page
```

I need to load the picture "mainImage,jpg" as soon as possible and display it on the page.

Preferably, the order would be like that or better:

```
second.html
mainImage.jpg
first.html 
...........
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't possible without knowing the image urls and preloading them prior to calling them.

In your described scenario, where template pages are being loaded, it doesn't seem like this is an option.

The reason why what you are observing is happening is because the server for your jsp is composing the html. So the html is all composed into the stream writer for the source code. Once the source code is sent to the browser, it then renders the source. It will request the images as they are encountered in the source.

There is no way to mix the image requests with the html composure because they are two separate actions. One is composing a string for a stream writer, and the other is making network requests for external resources.

The only hope if you are trying to change this is to cache the external resources prior to them being requested.

One way to attempt to preload the image would be to save it to a variable in the head of the document using JavaScript

```
<head>
    ...other related head elements...
    <script>
        (function cache(){
           var mainCache = new Image();
           mainCache.src = "mainImage.jpg";
        })()
    </script>
```

This approach will at least start the loading process immediately upon the page starting up, however depending on the image size it may still be loading as the page renders.

Comment: Wouldn't a nasty hack be to not include any resources but the image, and instead load them in with e.g. AJAX as soon as DOMContentLoaded is fired? That way the image is shown when the page is rendered, and the remaining resources are then added afterwards.

Comment: @eli - Yes, you could also go the route of offering what many sites use as a "loading screen" which displays some sort of animation while the images populate in the preloading cache. It isn't a terrible hack, that is certainly a viable alternative.